# Find the number of ways in which the number $6561^2$ can be written as a product of $3$ factors.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, factoring

Here is how I tried to solve this :- 
$6561^2=3^{16}$
Number of factors for $3^{16} = 17$
Now $3^{16}=3^a\cdot3^b\cdot3^c$ in order to get $3^{16}$ as a product of $3$ numbers. Now 
$a+b+c=16$ and we can use whole number distribution to get the number of ways which is $^{18}C_2 = 153$ number of ways but this is not the correct answer. What am I missing here? Please help me on this !!!

Is there any method to calculate the whole number distribution where all the numbers are distinct? I think I need to find the distinct powers of $3$. How many $3$ unique numbers can add up to 16 I guess that I should be looking for?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Is there any method to calculate the whole number distribution where all the numbers are distinct?

Comment: Does the original problem require that all the factors are distinct, or do you have two separate problems? Also, you need to be more clear in your problem regarding what is considered distinct or not. Would $3^8\times 3^8\times 3^0$ be considered a distinct way of multiplying than $3^0\times 3^8\times 3^8$?

Comment: This is the only problem statement and I think it is asking for unordered pair of solutions because the correct answer provided for this is 30.

Comment: Are the factors required to be positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Based on your answer of 30,) What you want is the number of multi-sets $\{a, b, c\}$ whose product is $3^{16}$.
What this means is that $\{1, 1, 3^{16}\}, \{3^{16}, 1, 1\}$ should only be counted once. (Whereas when you do $a+b+c = 16$, you counted it 3 times.)

**Hint:** Essentially apply Polya Enumeration Theorem / Burnside lemma.

- Number of triples of the form $\{a, a, a\} - 0$.
- Number of triples of the form $\{a, a, b\} - 9$.
- Number of triples of the form $\{a, b, c\} - \frac{153 - 9\times 3}{6} = 21$
- Hence, total number of triples is $ 0 + 9 + 21 = 30$.

Now, I leave it to you to explain the above steps.

Comment: At first I couldn’t clearly see the application of Polya/Burnside here, but this is exactly a case of weighted Polya! I mean, if you wanna sledgehammer it